# Calculating median on a excel file

Tags: regex, excel

I want to calculate the medians for a series of numbers from an excel file. 
My excel spreadsheet looks like this:

```
CELLNOUN 9.32
CELLNOUN 10.62
CELLNOUN 8.42
CELLNOUN 10.64
CELLNOUN 11.51
CELLNOUN 12.01
CELLNOUN 8.83
CELLSNOUN/CELLNOUN 9.53
CELLSNOUN/CELLNOUN 9.21
CELLNOUN/CELLSNOUN 10.76
CELLNOUN/CELLSNOUN 7.01
CELLSNOUN/CELLNOUN 10.21

PLANTNOUN/PLANTSNOUN 3.62
PLANTNOUN/PLANTSNOUN 3.38
PLANTSNOUN/PLANTNOUN 3.92
PLANTSNOUN/PLANTNOUN 3.24
PLANTNOUN/PLANTSNOUN 3.83
PLANTNOUN/PLANTSNOUN 3.24
PLANTSNOUN/PLANTNOUN 3.00
PLANTSNOUN/PLANTNOUN 1.80

...
```

In the spreadsheet, each set of words has been separated by a blank row, but the numbers of the entries for each set varies, like CELLNOUN/CELLSNOUN has 12 entries but PLANTNOUN/ has 8 entries. The numbers coming after the words are, in fact, the occurrences of these words. I want to find out the median of the occurrences for CELLNOUN/CELLSNOUN, PLANTNOUN/PLANTSNOUN etc, by using Regex instead of using the MEDIAN function in Excel to do it, because I have thousands of sets like this and I can't do it one by one on Excel. But if you know a quicker way to do it on Excel, please advice.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Vicky Its a good idea to give a small test example and what the actual answer should be. We cannot see the wood for the forest or should I say cells here. take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remove the blank rows from your data set and then create an Excel Table with Insert > Table or Ctrl-T. With an Excel table object, all functions and commands that refer to the table will catch when more data is added to the table.

Now you can create a pivot table from your source data with Insert > PivotTable. If you drag the first column field into the rows area, you will have a list of unique values in that source data column. You can drag the values column into the Values area of the Pivot Panel, if you want to. This should now look similar to this screenshot:

[image]

I'm not sure if you are aware of the different spellings of your categories, i.e. with or without an "S". The pivot table uncovers them all.

Out of the box, Excel PivotTables do not offer the Median as an option to aggregate, but you can use a method outlined here

http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/calculating-median-in-pivottables

to calculate a median.

The exact approach varies depending on whether or not you use Pivot tables or Power Pivot, so check out the article.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array formula as shown below and press `ctrl+shift+enter` to make it an array formula:

```
=MEDIAN((IF($A$1:$A$20=A1,$B$1:$B$20)))
```

Refer to the formula bar in the image below to apply to all cells by applying the same formula to all cells
[image]